# DRY approach on android

Tags: android, button, layout, copy, dry

During development of Android application, I noticed that I use multiple buttons, that the different between them is the Id, the text and the onclick function.
So I implemented a different XML file holding 1 styled button, and when I want to use a button I just import it into the required layout.
But then I realized I have a new problem: I don't know how to set all the different parameters at each imported button...

Is there a method to perform this and stick to DRY approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you need multiple buttons, you will need to give them different identifiers. You can do this in your import declaration like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/your_button"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton" />
```

Then, you can reference them by ID like usual:

```
Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
loginButton.setText("Login");
```

However, I am not sure this is a better approach than just declaring your buttons as needed in XML. If you want to avoid repeating styling, you can define a custom style for your button and apply it in the XML declaration. See the [docs on styling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) for more information.

Below is an example from the docs with an `EditText`.

In the styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomText" parent="@style/Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText
    style="@style/CustomText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, World!" />
```

Comment: Actually the correct syntax is <include layout="..." /> and not import. But great! this is just what I wanted